# Реализация хэш алгоритма RIPEMD-160

Tags: qt, хеширование

Прошерстил множество сайтов(однообразных), википедий и прочих разборов этого алгоритма, но к сожалению при реализации алгоритма получить стандартные хэши для ""(пустой строки), "а" и ряда других типичных строк так и не удалось.
http://solutionmes.wikidot.com/crypto-ripemd
https://crypto.stackovernet.com/ru/q/7465
Код привожу ниже

```
#include "ripemd.h"
#include "ui_ripemd.h"
#include <QDebug>

RIPEMD::RIPEMD(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::RIPEMD)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

RIPEMD::~RIPEMD()
{
    delete ui;
}

// Определяем функции и константы для RIPEMD-160
quint32 logicFun(quint32 j, quint32 x, quint32 y, quint32 z)
{
    if      (j <= 15) return x ^ y ^ z;
    else if (j <= 31) return (x & y) | (~x & z);
    else if (j <= 47) return (x | ~y) ^ z;
    else if (j <= 63) return (x & z) | (y & ~z);
    else if (j <= 79) return x ^ (y | ~z);
    else return 0;
}

quint32 rotateLeft(quint32 x, quint32 n)
{
    return (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32-(n))));
}
//Константы для первого потока
quint32 cnst1(quint32 j)
{
    if      (j <= 15) return 0x00000000;
    else if (j <= 31) return 0x5A827999;
    else if (j <= 47) return 0x6ED9EBA1;
    else if (j <= 63) return 0x8F1BBCDC;
    else if (j <= 79) return 0xA953FD4E;
    else return 0;
}
//Константы для второго потока
quint32 cnst2(quint32 j)
{
    if      (j <= 15) return 0x50A28BE6;
    else if (j <= 31) return 0x5C4DD124;
    else if (j <= 47) return 0x6D703EF3;
    else if (j <= 63) return 0x7A6D76E9;
    else if (j <= 79) return 0x00000000;
    else return 0;
}
// Наборы значений для выборки из заданного сообщения
quint32 Viborka1[] =
{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
    7, 4, 13, 1, 10, 6, 15, 3, 12, 0, 9, 5, 2, 14, 11, 8,
    3, 10, 14, 4, 9, 15, 8, 1, 2, 7, 0, 6, 13, 11, 5, 12,
    1, 9, 11, 10, 0, 8, 12, 4, 13, 3, 7, 15, 14, 5, 6, 2,
    4, 0, 5, 9, 7, 12, 2, 10, 14, 1, 3, 8, 11, 6, 15, 13
};

quint32 Viborka2[] =
{
    5, 14, 7, 0, 9, 2, 11, 4, 13, 6, 15, 8, 1, 10, 3, 12,
    6, 11, 3, 7, 0, 13, 5, 10, 14, 15, 8, 12, 4, 9, 1, 2,
    15, 5, 1, 3, 7, 14, 6, 9, 11, 8, 12, 2, 10, 0, 4, 13,
    8, 6, 4, 1, 3, 11, 15, 0, 5, 12, 2, 13, 9, 7, 10, 14,
    12, 15, 10, 4, 1, 5, 8, 7, 6, 2, 13, 14, 0, 3, 9, 11
};

// Наборы значений для циклического сдвига
quint32 CyRoll1[] =
{
    11, 14, 15, 12, 5, 8, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 6, 7, 9, 8,
    7, 6, 8, 13, 11, 9, 7, 15, 7, 12, 15, 9, 11, 7, 13, 12,
    11, 13, 6, 7, 14, 9, 13, 15, 14, 8, 13, 6, 5, 12, 7, 5,
    11, 12, 14, 15, 14, 15, 9, 8, 9, 14, 5, 6, 8, 6, 5, 12,
    9, 15, 5, 11, 6, 8, 13, 12, 5, 12, 13, 14, 11, 8, 5, 6
};

quint32 CyRoll2[] =
{
    8, 9, 9, 11, 13, 15, 15, 5, 7, 7, 8, 11, 14, 14, 12, 6,
    9, 13, 15, 7, 12, 8, 9, 11, 7, 7, 12, 7, 6, 15, 13, 11,
    9, 7, 15, 11, 8, 6, 6, 14, 12, 13, 5, 14, 13, 13, 7, 5,
    15, 5, 8, 11, 14, 14, 6, 14, 6, 9, 12, 9, 12, 5, 15, 8,
    8, 5, 12, 9, 12, 5, 14, 6, 8, 13, 6, 5, 15, 13, 11, 11
};

void RIPEMD::on_generate_clicked()
{
    // Считываем сообщение из формы
    QByteArray message = ui->msg->text().toUtf8();
    // Добавляем 1 в конец, затем дополняем необходимым количеством 0
    message.append((quint8)128);
    quint32 bytesCount = message.size();
    quint32 zerosNum = (bytesCount % 64) < 56 ? 56 - (bytesCount % 64): 56 + 64 - (bytesCount % 64);
    for (int i = 0; i < zerosNum; i++) message.append((quint8)0);
    // Переводим bytes в quint32
    QVector<quint32> msg(message.size() / 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < message.size() / 4 ; i++)
    {
        msg[i] = ((quint8)message[i*4 + 3] << 24) |
                 ((quint8)message[i*4 + 2] << 16) |
                 ((quint8)message[i*4 + 1] << 8)  |
                 ((quint8)message[i*4 + 0]);
    }
    // Дополняем 64 битами, указывающими на количество исходных бит
    // Разделяем 64 бита на две части по 32, младшие 32 бита добавляются в первую очередь
    quint64 msgLen = (bytesCount-1)  * 8;
    quint32 one = msgLen & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    quint32 two = msgLen >> 32;
    msg.append(one);
    msg.append(two);
    // Инициализация регистров
    quint32 H0 = 0x67452301;
    quint32 H1 = 0xEFCDAB89;
    quint32 H2 = 0x98BADCFE;
    quint32 H3 = 0x10325476;
    quint32 H4 = 0xC3D2E1F0;
    // Производим расчет по алгоритму
    for (quint32 i = 0; i < (msg.size() / 16); i++)
        {
            // Временные регистры для двух потоков
            quint32 A1 = H0;
            quint32 B1 = H1;
            quint32 C1 = H2;
            quint32 D1 = H3;
            quint32 E1 = H4;
            quint32 A2 = H0;
            quint32 B2 = H1;
            quint32 C2 = H2;
            quint32 D2 = H3;
            quint32 E2 = H4;
            quint32 TT = 0;
            for (quint32 j = 0; j <= 79; j++)
            {
                TT = rotateLeft((A1 + logicFun(     j, B1, C1, D1) + msg[Viborka1[j] + j/16 * i] + cnst1(j)), CyRoll1[j]) + E1;
                A1 = E1, E1 = D1, D1 = rotateLeft(C1, 10), C1 = B1, B1 = TT;
                TT = rotateLeft((A2 + logicFun(79 - j, B2, C2, D2) + msg[Viborka2[j] + j/16 * i] + cnst2(j)), CyRoll2[j]) + E2;
                A2 = E2, E2 = D2, D2 = rotateLeft(C2, 10), C2 = B2, B2 = TT;
            }
            // Обновляем значения регистров
            TT = H1 + C1 + D2;
            H1 = H2 + D1 + E2;
            H2 = H3 + E1 + A2;
            H3 = H4 + A1 + B2;
            H4 = H0 + B1 + C2;
            H0 = TT;
        }
    QString outputStr = QString::number(H0,16) + QString::number(H1,16) + QString::number(H2,16) + QString::number(H3,16) + QString::number(H4,16);
    ui->result->setText(outputStr);
}
// RIPEMD-160("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") =
// 37f332f68db77bd9d7edd4969571ad671cf9dd3b
// RIPEMD-160("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cog") =
// 132072df690933835eb8b6ad0b77e7b6f14acad7
// RIPEMD-160("") =
// 9c1185a5c5e9fc54612808977ee8f548b2258d31 "истинный" хэш пустой строки
// Что выходит на деле
// Пустая строка
// a585119c54fce9c59708286148f5e87e318d25b2
// Строка "а"
// 2d9ddc0be93e6b257b34aeda83dcf4e6fe7f465a
```

Comment: Отладка хеш-функций трудоемкая задача, вряд ли кто-то будет делать ее вместо вас. Берите готовую реализацию на любом языке программирования и сравнивайте в режиме отладки промежуточные результаты.

Comment: Просто быть может в реализации мной было что-то упущено, или интерпретированной мной неправильно?